# How to query for direct childs of entity in GAE Datastore(HRD)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We can get all children of y (including indirect), by X.all().ancestor(y), but I want to receive only those which are direct children of y.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
X.all().filter("parent = ", y)
```

Comment: I think you got it inverted. I think he's looking to query for the direct children of y. I think it should be X.all().filter("parent = ", y).

Comment: This will only work if you have a datastore property called 'parent'.

Comment: @NickJohnson I'm pretty sure I saw this somewhere in GAE docs, can't find it now. So there is no way of querying for direct ancestors?

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Only if you explicitly cater for it by adding a property to filter on.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Datastore [Query()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query) you can set its ancestor by using the method [setAncestor()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query#setAncestor(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key)) but it does not guarantee that the ancestor is the direct parent.

What you can do to ensure fetching only the direct children is by doing a comparison operation.

```
if( directChildEntity.getKey().getParent().equals( directParentEntity.getKey() ) )
        {
        // directChildEntity is a direct child of directParentEntity
        }
```

The trick is to use the Datastore [Key's getParent()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key#getParent()) method since it can mediate a one-step hierarchy between keys.